# Transform IEnumerable(Of DataRow()) into List(Of Datarow)

Tags: vb.net, linq, ienumerable

I have a `DataSet` with relations for two `DataTable`s.
This `Dataset` is my `DataSource` in a grid.
In other site of my app, I use this `DataSource` as `DataTable`. The relation allows me use `ChildRelations`.

I need all `DataRow`s in one list.

The first part is (`DTpadre` and `DThijo` are `DataTable`s):

```
DS = New DataSet()
DS.Tables.Add(DTpadre.Copy)
DS.Tables.Add(DThijo.Copy)
DS.Relations.Add("PERMISOS", DS.Tables(0).Columns("CORR"), DS.Tables(1).Columns("CORR_PADRE"), False)
gridDetallePerfiles.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
```

What I tried is:

```
DTprincipal = DirectCast(gridDetallePerfiles.DataSource, DataTable)
Dim obj = (From a As DataRelation In DTprincipal.ChildRelations() Select a.ChildTable.Select())
```

but `obj` is `IEnumerable(Of DataRow())`... I want `IEnumerable(Of Datarow)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.ChildTable` is a `DataTable`.
`a.ChildTable.Select()` is a call to the [`Select()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataTable_Select) of the `DataTable` that returns an array of `DataRow`.
Hence the resulting type is `IEnumerable(Of an array of DataRow)`.

If you want to flatten all rows of all child tables into a single collection, use `SelectMany`:

```
Dim obj = DTprincipal.ChildRelations.Cast(Of DataRelation).SelectMany(Function(r) r.ChildTable.Select())
```

Comment: it works! i know selectmany but i tried replacing r.childtable.select ...bad try.